# use wildcard to copy folders using maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using maven-assembly-plugin to collect some files and folders in a .tar.gz file. In my target directory, I have some folders with these names (for example):

lib-oracle 
lib-mysql 
lib-sqlserver 
.
.

and each folder contains some jar files.

I want to copy these folders (and also contents of them) into a final .tar.gz file. I know I can copy them separately like this:

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>target/lib-oracle</directory>
    <outputDirectory>lib-oracle</outputDirectory>
</fileSet>
```

but I'm interested to know if there is any way to copy them all together?
maybe something like this:

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>target/lib*</directory>
</fileSet>
```

Answer (score 14):

finally I was successful to do it:

```
<fileSet>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>lib*/*</include>
        </includes>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
```

Comment: If you want to selected the subfolders on any level use lib**/*.

Comment: This copies only the folders. How to copy folders and files on any level?

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>target/</directory>
    <outputDirectory>lib-oracle</outputDirectory>
</fileSet>`
```

Even this will allow you to get all the data from inside target folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>target</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>lib-oracle/**</include>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </includes>
</fileSet>
```

'**' indicates all the files in the current folder and all the files in the subfolders of the current folder.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this configuration

```
<include>**/*</include>
```

and it copies all the sub-folder and files in the sub-folder, except the empty sub-folder. I think it is logic and enough.